# How to Point application-context-test.xml and web.xml to Embedded Jetty?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to start up an embedded Jetty within my test class. I've written that code:

```
  server = new Server(TEST_PORT);

  ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
  sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
  sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "org.gogo.rena.rest");
  sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
  ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
  context.setContextPath("/");
  context.addServlet(sh, "/*");

  server.setHandler(context);
  try {
     server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
     server.start();
     //server.join();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     fail("Error has occurred while starting! Error is as follows: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

How can I point application-context-test.xml and web.xml to my embedded Jetty (they are at different places.)

Comment: I don't think you need a web.xml, since you are doing embeded Jetty.  I know with Spring Boot you don't need it.  I think You configure your servlets manually.  As for your App Context, is it in the classpath?  Shouldn't the DispatchServlet be reading that in?

Comment: @CodeChimp You are right, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a web.xml, since you are doing embedded Jetty. I know with Spring Boot you don't need it. I think You configure your servlets manually. As for your App Context, is it in the classpath? Shouldn't the DispatchServlet be reading that in?